# coveralls fails on AppVeyor in some builds but not in others

Tags: coveralls, appveyor

I'm trying to make [pytest](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/pull/1350) publish coverage reports from AppVeyor. I've added the repository's encrypted token as explained [here](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-configuration#secure-variables). Here's the `appveyor.yml` file:

```
environment:
  COVERALLS_REPO_TOKEN:
    secure: 2NJ5Ct55cHJ9WEg3xbSqCuv0rdgzzb6pnzOIG5OkMbTndw3wOBrXntWFoQrXiMFi
    # this is pytest's token in coveralls.io, encrypted
    # using pytestbot account as detailed here:
    # https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-configuration#secure-variables

install:
  - echo Installed Pythons
  - dir c:\Python*

  # install pypy using choco (redirect to a file and write to console in case
  # choco install returns non-zero, because choco install python.pypy is too
  # noisy)
  - choco install python.pypy > pypy-inst.log 2>&1 || (type pypy-inst.log & exit /b 1)
  - set PATH=C:\tools\pypy\pypy;%PATH% # so tox can find pypy
  - echo PyPy installed
  - pypy --version

  - C:\Python35\python -m pip install tox

build: false  # Not a C# project, build stuff at the test step instead.

test_script:
  # - C:\Python35\python -m tox  
  - C:\Python35\python -m tox -e coveralls  # coveralls is not in tox's envlist
```

Now the weird thing is, some builds pass others do not. The GH panel for continuous integration on the [PR](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/pull/1350) shows that the build for the `continuous-integration/appveyor/branch` passes and publishes coverage as expected, but fails for the `continuous-integration/appveyor/pr` build with this message:

```
You have to provide either repo_token in .coveralls.yml, or launch via Travis or CircleCI
ERROR: InvocationError: 'C:\\projects\\pytest\\.tox\\coveralls\\Scripts\\coveralls.EXE'
```

Does anyone have any idea what's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Secure variables are not set during PR builds for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was suspecting that... but does that mean that all PRs would fail from now on?

Comment: Well, yes. Unless AppVeyor provides a built-in mechanism for uploading coveralls.io results. Is it possible with python to decouple running tests and saving results in some form and then sending those results to coveralls.io?

Comment: The solution I adopted was to simply skip uploading coveralls results if the `COVERALLS_REPO_TOKEN` is not available... time will tell if this will bring other problems or not. Thanks again for your response, I'm accepting it.